# android: layout background turns black after hiding another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have activity that display some info about school, and subscribe button
[image]

when the subscribe button is pressed, it shows another layout with edittext and button to enter subscription code
[image]

no the problem, if i pressed cancel the i got black background in the middle
[image]

this is the activity layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollingCache="false"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:background="#333"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/followOrgImage"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Untitled!"
                android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/followTextDate"
            android:textColor="#8B8B8B" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/followTextDesc"
            android:textColor="#C4C4C4" />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/followTextCountry"
            android:textColor="#fafafa" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"

            >
        <Button
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/follow"
                android:id="@+id/follow_btn"
                android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ddd" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/subscribe"
                android:id="@+id/subscribe_btn"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ddd" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:scrollingCache="false"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/subscribe_layout"
            >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="186dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/subscribe_edit_txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:hint="@string/profiles_code_hint" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/addBtn"
                android:id="@+id/subscribe_add_btn"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ddd" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/organization_type"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#B1B1B1"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#444"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:id="@+id/typeTxt"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/address"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textSize="15sp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#B1B1B1"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="#444"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/addressTxt"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:visibility="gone">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hdnBtn"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i tried to give some layouts this attributes

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

but it didn't solve it

any suggestions?

Comment: Change the entire theme of the application and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By seeing your requirement, There is no need of the extra tags that you have used like cacheColorHint.

Simply, show the first screen, then navigate the user to new screen on subscribe button click.
You need 2 different xml layouts for it.

Or 2nd approach could be, On click of Subscribe button, set visibility of old elements to gone and set visibility of new required elements to visible.